# Distribute custom StyleCop rules amongst team members

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

I have created a number of custom StyleCop rules that incorporates some special style requirements that were agreed upon in our development team.

The StyleCop SDK documentation (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/downloads/get/324789) states that:

> Custom StyleCop rules can be installed by simply copying the assembly containing the rules to the directory that contains StyleCop.dll, or any subdirectory under that directory.

For this to work Visual Studio needs to be closed when using StyleCop for ReSharper.

I expect to be introducing new rules and bugfixes continuously. Is there a good way to distribute new versions of the DLL file containing the custom rules among the team, other than writing a mail to everybody, asking them to close Visual Studio and copy it over the existing file?

Comment: You could try looking at [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/). I've never used it and have no idea if its any good, but as it "extends original StyleCop features" it may support what you need.

Comment: StyleCop+ looks nice, but it does not seem to support distribution features.

Comment: Have you considered to use the rule-file instead a dll? We do it in this way, so everyone can modify the file an distribute it via svn (or what ever you use). Works very well.

Comment: We do distribute the rules file by our source control versioning system too, but how could I make custom rules (i.e. new rules that I have written myself by inheriting from the SourceAnalyzer class) without distributing the dll?

Comment: @Rosted msbuild task supports `AdditionalAddinPaths` property, which can be used for setting additional paths to directories where you want to load your addins (and I guess that StyleCop console app also should have it). But I don't think that you can set them in VS (to support R#).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. While it doesn't seem to solve my problem in VS, it is useful for the CI builds.

Comment: Distribute your custom DLL through source control as well. If you need to make changes to it, then do so, check out the DLL, replace it with your new DLL, check it in, and tell your team to get latest, and it should pull down your new DLL and they should be ready to go. At least, theoretically.

Comment: The problem is that the DLL must be in the StyleCop installation dir. So source control is not really an option as far as I see it. Right now the team do get it from our Git repository, but they will still have to copy it over manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) with NuGet. Make a local Chocolatey NuGet repository on a network share, and then the updates can be managed via a package installer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at how this works. Will it allow copying the file into the StyleCop installation directory?

Comment: it should, anything power shell can do chocolatey should be able to do